# What is Silent Lake?

Tags: trusted-computing, intel, tee

The Wikipédia's [TEE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trusted_execution_environment#Implementations) entry mentions a hardware technology called *Silent Lake* that can support TEE implementations:

> The following embedded hardware technologies can be used to support
>   TEE implementations:
>
> - ...
> - Intel:
>
>   - Trusted Execution Technology
>   - SGX Software Guard Extensions
>   - **"Silent Lake" (available on Atom processors)**

(The three references it provides don't say much, and a web searching did't return useful results.)

Is Silent Lake a real thing, and what (security) properties does it provide?

---

Resources (official documentation would be terrific):

- https://github.com/lenovo-yt2-dev/android_hardware_intel_kernelflinger/commit/cd0dd74a94438778881a202f6fb7c327552f6bde